# NodeJs - Pass values through condition statement to a callback and get value back

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

In my route file I have a condition where an external function checks if two values are equal, `obj.id === getId` and accordingly to `true` or `false` it renders the view or it blocks the user.

The function `checkUser` which I try to work as a callback, it gets the values which are being pass to it but I cannot get back the result of `true` or `false` to my route file.

> **Route file**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const fcs = require('../routes/functions') //Global functions file

    router.get('/:id', fcs.isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {

    getId = req.params.id

    db.con.query('SELECT * FROM employees where id=?', getId, function(err, results, callback) {

        if (err) {
            //some code
            return

        } else {

            try {

                //some code for getting results to obj{}

                // here is the checking point that will use the callback   
                if (fcs.checkUser(obj.id, getId)) {
                    res.render('showuser')

                } else {
                    //some code
                }

            } catch (err) {
                //some code
            }
        }
    })
})
```

> **Global Functions file**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

module.exports.checkUser = function checkUser(uid, id, callback) {

    // it gets true or false with no problem
    console.log(uid === id)

    // Need to send the output of true or false back to the condition checker (route file)
    callback(uid === id) 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass another callback.
For Your callback implementation it should probably look like this:

```
// here is the checking point that will use the callback   
fcs.checkUser(obj.id, getId, function(userValid){
    if(userValid){
        res.render('showuser');
    } else {
         // some code
    }
));
```

Node-style callback:

```
// here is the checking point that will use the callback   
fcs.checkUser(obj.id, getId, function(err, userValid){
    if(userValid){
        res.render('showuser');
    } else {
         // some code
    }
));
```

Than your `checkUser` should call callback like this: `callback(null, uid === id);`

Comment: Why do I have to put `null` in `callback(null, uid === id)` ?

Comment: In your current implementation you don't have to. I provide a version of node-style callback (maybe I shouldn't have done that). In node most of callbacks have such signature `function cb(err, data)`. In this case you would have to pass `null` for `error`. But you don't have to. Sorry for confusion.